# Android: findViewById on Fragment Item returns null

Tags: android, listview, fragment

i cant figure it out.

When sometimes clicks on an Item in my ListView, i want to open a Fragment and set 1 EditText and 3 RadioButtons according to the values of the list item that was clicked.

```
public void openEditTask(int position) {
    if (newTaskFragment != null) closeNewTaskFragment();
    if (editTaskFragment != null) closeEditTaskFragment();

    editTaskFragment = new EditTaskFragment();
    transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_right);
    transaction.replace(R.id.edit_task_frame_xml, editTaskFragment);

    //set EditText and RadioButtons according to clicked item
    EditText editTaskName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_task_name_xml);
    RadioButton easyButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.edit_radio_button_easy_xml);
    RadioButton mediumButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.edit_radio_button_medium_xml);
    RadioButton hardButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.edit_radio_button_hard_xml);
    //Edit Text
    editTaskName.setText(mTaskList.get(position).getName());
    //Radio Buttons
    if (mTaskList.get(position).getDifficultyNumber() == 1) {
        easyButton.isChecked();
    } else if (mTaskList.get(position).getDifficultyNumber() == 2) {
        mediumButton.isChecked();
    } else hardButton.isChecked();

    transaction.commit();

}
```

Why do i get a null pointer exception? I dont understand it.

Comment: You should add your EditTaskFragment implementation inside EditTaskFragment.java class.

Comment: You mean the part where i set all the views? How would that work? Should i make a constructor which passes the values of the clicked item to the Fragment? And where do i put the logic for setting the views? In onCreate()?
Sorry, im still a beginner.

Comment: I guess it doesnt really matter where i pass the values, because i can just make a method for that, right?

Comment: Could you add your EditTaskFragment.java

Comment: I got it to work by putting everything into onCreateView of the Fragment and passing the necessary information (the text and which radiobuttons are clicked) as arguments for the Fragment. Is that a good approach? However, i still dont understand why i couldnt get the views from the activity, because i have a very similar method that works.

Comment: I realized that findViewById works when we pass "View v" in an onclick method (in an xml file). So it needs the "View v" for findViewById?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle your instances in the Fragment class. You can set the position as an Argument and get the data from wherever you need and show the view.

Your **EditTaskFragment** should look something like this:

```
public class EditTaskFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String POSITION_PARAM = "positionParam";

    private int position;

    public EditTaskFragment() {
    }

    public static EditTaskFragment newInstance(int position) {
        EditTaskFragment fragment = new EditTaskFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(POSITION_PARAM, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            position = getArguments().getInt(POSITION_PARAM);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourfragmentlayout, container, false);
        EditText editTaskName = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edit_task_name_xml);
        RadioButton easyButton = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.edit_radio_button_easy_xml);
        RadioButton mediumButton = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.edit_radio_button_medium_xml);
        RadioButton hardButton = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.edit_radio_button_hard_xml);
        //Edit Text
        editTaskName.setText(mTaskList.get(position).getName());
        //Radio Buttons
        if (mTaskList.get(position).getDifficultyNumber() == 1) {
            easyButton.isChecked();
        } else if (mTaskList.get(position).getDifficultyNumber() == 2) {
            mediumButton.isChecked();
        } else
            hardButton.isChecked();

        return v;
      }    
}
```

Then, your **openEditTask** function should be:

```
public void openEditTask(int position) {
    if (newTaskFragment != null) closeNewTaskFragment();
    if (editTaskFragment != null) closeEditTaskFragment();

    editTaskFragment = EditTaskFragment.newInstance(position);
    transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_right);
    transaction.replace(R.id.edit_task_frame_xml, editTaskFragment);    
    transaction.commit();

}
```

So, you have to look for the data according the position the user selected, in the Fragment class.

I hope this answer your question

Comment: Thank you, those are exactly the changes i have made. One more question: Should i also handle all the button clicks of the Frament's View in the Fragment itself? Because its much easier to set an onClickListener in the Activity which contains the Fragment (because i can call it over the XML onclick attribute).

Comment: Yes, you should call the OnclickListener in the fragment class itself. Then, the actions you need to do can pass it back to the activity using interfaces, as states [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity)

Comment: Thank you, thats understandable.

Comment: If you need some example, and if you're using Android Studio, you can see how to do that if you create a fragment using the wizard. I mean, right-click in your package where you put your classes, select New->Fragment->Fragment (with a +1 button) and then keep checked the option of "Include interface callbacks" and then you can see how they implement the onClick event

Comment: And what if a Fragment Button is just used to close the Fragment? Should i still first handle it in the Fragment, even though all the closing-logic is in the Activity?

Comment: Well, I think you should. What I usually do is to handle callbacks in my activity, and if the callback means to close the fragment I do it in the activity. The callbacks are just for communicating with the activity when you need (because the views from the fragment are managed in the fragment class). However, the actions you need to performe are coded in the Activity class.

Comment: Ok,  i understand. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, one more thing: When you set the Listeners for the Fragments Views and Buttons, does that all happen in the onCreateView method? 
Isnt that a bit messy?

Comment: Sorry, I went to sleep. It is intended that you perform all that actions in the onCreateView because it happens after the onCreate method. In the onCreateView you have access to your views (and not in the onCreate, that's why you have an inflater as an argument), so you can setup all your views there. If you think it is a little bit messy, you can do it creating your own functions ;)